# Can't change wordpress url when conditions are met

Tags: php, wordpress, url, hook

Hey I've got this code

```
add_filter('site_url','wpse_search_filter');
function wpse_search_filter(){
    $string = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if(str_contains($string, "?s=")){
        $new_url = $string."&post_type=product";
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.location.href = <?= $new_url; ?>;
</script>
    <?php
    }   
}
```

Which is in the functions.php file in my child theme. I'm trying to change the url to have '&post_type=product' at the end if the url contains '?s='. I'm confident that this code should work however it isn't doing anything. Is the hook wrong or am I missing something else?

UPDATE:

After changing the code to

```
add_filter('site_url','wpse_search_filter');
function wpse_search_filter(){
    $string = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if(str_contains($string, "?s=")){
        $new_url = $string."&post_type=product";
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.location.href = "<?= $new_url; ?>";
</script>
    <?php
    }   
}
```

I now have an error where '&post_type=product' is added to the url an infinite amount of times. I've tried to fix it with this code however it is not working:

```
add_filter('site_url','wpse_search_filter');
function wpse_search_filter(){
    $string = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if(!str_contains($string, "&post_type=product")){
        if(str_contains($string, "?s=")){
            $new_url = $string."&post_type=product";
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.location.href = "<?= $new_url; ?>";
    </script>
    <?php
            }   
    }
    
}
```

How could I fix this problem, Thanks.

Comment: Look in your browsers development console. You will most likely get an JS error on `document.location.href = <?= $new_url; ?>;` since you're missing any quotes around the url (which is a string). Try: `document.location.href = "<?= $new_url; ?>";` instead. However, if this code is executed before any other output at all (which it should be), just redirect the user using PHP instead `header("location: $new_url");`.

Comment: WordPress has two types of “hooks”, actions and filters. When an action is used, you can emit HTML, send HTTP headers, etc., but when a filter is used, you are given a value, and often some additional context, and asked your opinion of that value and if you’d like it changed. Filters _must_ return a value, and emitting HTML in a filter is usually not a good idea. The code you have posted is a filter.

Comment: This very specific filter is called at the end of the `get_site_url()` function. The goal of that function is to generally answer the question “what is the URL of the site where WordPress lives”, which can also be thought of as “what URL could I append `/wp-admin/` to in order to get to the backend of the site. This function can be called many times, and the output might even be sent directly to an HTML attribute.

Comment: Thanks @M.Eriksson , this worked and my site now gets to the page I want however my URL looks like this: ?s=a&post_type=product&post_type=product&post_type=product&post_type=product&post_type=product&post_type=product&post_type=product&post_type=product&post_type=product so it keeps adding the product type part. I've changed my code to this:

Comment: ```
add_filter('site_url','wpse_search_filter');
function wpse_search_filter(){
    $string = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 if(!str_contains($string, "&post_type=product")){
  if(str_contains($string, "?s=")){
   $new_url = $string."&post_type=product";
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  document.location.href = "<?= $new_url; ?>";
 </script>
 <?php
   }   
 }
    
}``` however it's not working. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76495809/edit) your question if you want to add any updates to it (add it to the end of the question) instead of adding info/code blocks as comments.

Comment: Although it might appear to be working, I can almost guarantee using it this will way will break. [Here’s one example from core.](https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentyone/blob/ba9f20cad89163761185c0467b346ba42541ae22/inc/template-functions.php#L398) The function `site_url` calls `get_site_url` which calls that filter. If you echo anything, it will go into the form’s action attribute which would be invalid. You need to find another solution.

Comment: Maybe you should be looking at [`search_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/search_link/) instead.

Comment: okay thanks @ChrisHaas , I've changed the hook to search_link and it still works as I wanted it too.